# How to disable an select option in drop down list on mobile Safari

Tags: mobile, safari, mobile-safari

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable select option in IOS Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109085/disable-select-option-in-ios-safari)

How do we disable an  in ? I was setting the "disabled" attribute to "disabled" but that didn't work. I was using display:none but that didn't work either. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear. Try rewording the question or giving specific code snippet to illustrate your problem

Comment: I was asking how to disable an <option> in a <select> (make it greyed out). <option disabled="disabled"> doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I've answered with a definitive solution (at least for me) in the question for which this one is marked as a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31496732/1920145

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code snippet works in all decent browsers (read: Safari, Chrome, Firefox), and I tried it successfully in IE8 too:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">Option one</option>
  <option value="2">Option two</option>
  <option value="3" disabled="disabled">Option 3 (should be disabled)</option>
  <option value="4">Option four</option>
  <option value="5">option five</option>
</select>
```

… the end result being that all the options are listed, but option three is greyed-out and can't be selected. What behaviour are you seeing? And in what browser?

*EDIT*: OP clarified re using mobile Safari which doesn't support the `disabled` attribute, so the suggestion for devices using that browser (and similar) would be to remove the option entirely.

Comment: I use javascript to set an option to "disabled". It is disabled in FF, Chrome etc. However, on Mobile Safari, it's not greyed out and is still selectable.

Comment: OK, well you didn't say any of that in your original post, and you haven't provided the code, so we can't really help.

Comment: I used something as simple as $("select option").attr("disabled", "disabled") but it didn't work on mobile Safari. The options are not greyed out and are still selectable.

Comment: Looks like you're hitting the same issue as in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109085/disable-select-option-in-ios-safari The disabled state isn't honoured in Mobile Safari. I would alter the Javascript (for iOS browsers at least) so that instead of disabling the option, which doesn't have any effect, it simply removes it.

Comment: Thanks Ben. At least it's good to know that disabled="disabled" doesn't work in Mobile Safari.

Comment: This answer shouldn't even be accepted, as the "method" described works in no case for mobile browsers and the question specifically stated -mobile-... I've answered with a definitive solution (using innerHTML in here: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/31496732/1920145](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31496732/1920145)

Comment: The original question was _edited_ to add the mobile requirement, and that's clearly addressed in the answer too. How is your solution 'definitive'?