# Is it possible to make Combo box option unselectable without disabling it?

Tags: iphone, mobile, safari, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable select option in IOS Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109085/disable-select-option-in-ios-safari)

Since safari mobile browser do not support disabled="disabled" attribute hence I am looking for other way to make select box option look disabled may be through events or some other way around ?

```
<select>
<option value="monthly" disabled="disabled">Month</option> <!-- do not get disabled on iphone  -->
<option value="yearly">Yearly</option>
</select>
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's not a pretty solution, so I'm not going to suggest it as an answer, but you could use a radio button, with it's own separate group. This would work like a checkbox which could only be selected and not deselected. It's crude and I wouldn't recommend it though, but it's an option.

Comment: @MindWorX I do not want to change element to radio btn so please post any solution (pretty or not) it will be help-full .Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a:

```
onchange="selectValidate(this, 1)"
```

To your HTML and then in javascript:

```
function selectValidate(refSelect, defaultIndex)
{
     if(refSelect.options[refSelect.selectedIndex].hasAttribute("disabled"))
     {
           alert("You can't select that value");
           refSelect.selectedIndex=defaultIndex;
     }
}
```

Not tested but it should work.

---

FOR THE LOOK AND FEEL:

I think that you can use the CSS to specify your disabled items.

Example:

```
select option[disabled]
{
    background-color:#FBFBFB;
}
```

It may work on Safari as well since it's supposed to support CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Are you willing to use a jquery combo box plugin?
I googled for [this one](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown) and it seems to fit your requirements.