# Disable select option field in iPad

Tags: jquery, html, web-deployment

I have a drop down menu and I want to disable one option so people cant select it. But it doesnt seem to work on iPad. Do you guys know a way around this?

Comment: You'll have to provide your code or perhaps a JSFiddle. This should work.

Comment: Are you trying `.prop("disabled",true)`? http://jsfiddle.net/vuq2d/

Comment: @Udara Uragoda: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/qQG9V/

Use `disabled="disabled"` inside an `<option>` tag which you want to make disable.

**HTML**

```
<select>
    <option disabled="disabled">This is disabled</option>
    <option>test value 1</option>
    <option>test value 2</option>
</select>​
```

EDITED:

**By Using Jquery:**

```
$("select option[value*=Sold_Out]").prop('disabled',true);​
```

**HTML:**

```
<select>
    <option value="Sold_Out">This is disabled</option>
    <option>test value 1</option>
    <option value="Sold_Out">test value 2</option>
</select>​
```

**NOTE:** You have a space in the `value` of an `<option>` tag i.e `Sold Out`, that's why it is not working. Try to remove space or use `underscore _` symbol to make it work.

[**SEE WORKING FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/x5dHY/)

Comment: Im using this $("select option[value*='Sold Out']").prop('disabled',true);

Comment: Thanks. But If you look at the http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/qQG9V/ on an ipad, you still can select "This is disabled" option.

Comment: @Udara Uragoda: you have a space in a value `Sold Out` and it is not acceptable try using `underscore _` symbol or without space like `Sold_Out` See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/uZ5We/1/

Comment: Thanks A.K. But I still can select it on iPad. This is driving me nuts. Bloody iPad...

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871138/is-it-possible-to-make-combo-box-option-unselectable-without-disabling-it  ..Also See this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109085/disable-select-option-in-ios-safari

Answer (score 0):

use prop if you are using jQuery 1.6+

```
.prop('disabled',true);
.prop('disabled',false);
```

> The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method.