# Disabled <option> still selectable on iOS

Tags: html, ios, responsive-design, mobile-safari

I'm using a `select` as a navigation menu for mobile devices.

Because `optgroup` renders pretty badly on iOS, I've been using disabled options and hyphens to group some submenus.

ie:

```
<select>
    <option value="" disabled>Menu</option>
    <option value="sub1">- Sub 1</option>
    <option value="sub2">- Sub 2</option>
</select>
```

The disabled `option` is not selectable on desktop browsers, as expected. But on iOS, you can actually select it, even if it's greyed out. That then triggers my AJAX code to dynamically change page content and just creates a big mess.

I could "brute-force" cancel this by adding some `if` check statements in my AJAX function but I'm really wondering why disabled elements are selectable in the first place on iOS Safari?

[My site is here](http://rlcoaching.com) (you will have to resize to width < 700px on desktop, but need an iOS to select disabled elements)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable select option in IOS Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109085/disable-select-option-in-ios-safari)

Comment: I'm running into this same issue. However it seems to be specific to just Mobile Safari 8.0 and up. It is working as expected in Mobile Safari 7.0 and 6.0 on iphone 6 and 5. Were you able to come up with a solution do this?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to disabling the option, I got it to work by adding `display: none;` to the style attribute in the tag.

```
<option value="12000">$12,000</option>
<option value="15000">$15,000</option>
<option disabled="" style="display: none;" value="20000">$20,000</option>
<option disabled="" style="display: none;" value="25000">$25,000</option>
```

I'm not saying this is optimal, but it makes options not able to be selected for iOS Safari.