# Select disable property is not working for iOS in ionic1

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

```
 <ion-item class="item-divider item-icon-left item-icon-right item-avatar item-select viewtask-top">
    <p>Type:
      <select disabled="true" ng-model="taskDetails.type" ng-change="changeTaskType(taskDetails.type)"
              ng-options="taskType as taskType.name for taskType in taskTypes track by taskType.id">
      <select>
    </p>
  </ion-item>
```

Here I have added `disabled="true"` for disabling select option. This is working properly for android. But this is not working on iOS. How can I make this code to work on both Android and iOS?

Comment: You have by mistakenly tagged angularjs instead of android. please update the tags.

Comment: have you tried `disabled="disabled"`? Also see [the various answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109085/disable-select-option-in-ios-safari), the problem comes apparently from mobile safari. You could solve that by custom CSS (see `pointer-events`) or javascript `preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> CSS file

```
.style-disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

> HTML file

```
<ion-item class="item-divider item-icon-left item-icon-right item-avatar item-select viewtask-top">
            <p>Type:
              <select class="style-disabled" ng-model="taskDetails.type" ng-change="changeTaskType(taskDetails.type)"
                      ng-options="taskType as taskType.name for taskType in taskTypes track by taskType.id">
              <select>
            </p>
          </ion-item>
```